# system classloader does not use the overriden method

Tags: java, classloader

I have a program that generates classes using JCodemodel and a dynamic class loader. I parse a yaml file, generate the required classes and map the structure of the file . Everything is fine so far.

Snakeyaml handles the parse and write nicely, so the definition of classes if fine.

Then I try to access a method *properties()* which is redefined in the yaml.

I first load the file into a "Tree", load its root element as a "Compute" and print its class and methods ; then I call the overridden method.
The  *computeb* class is dynamicaly generated, as well as the *computeb$Properties*.

here is the code (I replaced my packages by shorter ones):

```
Tree tree = Parser.load(new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/tree.yaml"));
mypackage.Compute c = (mypackage.Compute) tree.root();
System.err.println("class : " + c.getClass());
for (Method m : c.getClass().getMethods()) {
  System.err.println(" method : " + m);
}
System.err.println("properties() class is " + c.properties().getClass().getName());
```

The result is :

> class : class computeb
>   method : public computeb$Property computeb.properties()
>   method : public mypackage.Compute$Property mypackage.Compute.properties()
>    (...)
>   properties() class is mypackage.Compute$Property

As you notice, the class has the two methods present, however the properties() method called is the second one.  I would want to call the first one (which is defined in the classloader) . Why does it happen this way ?  What should I do ?

Comment: Look like `c.properties()` return an object of `mypackage.Compute$Property`. Did you try to call `c.properties().properties()`?

Comment: Compute$Propertiy does not have a properties() method.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it, I had an issue while statically generating the classes on a specific folder.

Since I had to resolve existing classes to avoid creating them twice, I only resolved classes that were starting with my package prefix.

This worked well in static generation, but in dynamic generation I had previously generated classes I could not load, while they already were present. Basically that means that my class generator was creating another class with same name, so sometimes the classloader could refer to one class, sometimes to another.

I'm working on correcting this dirty mess.